# htaccess help needed

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm doing maintenance work on a cms and have found the following htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

i'm having trouble understanding it.
the reason a went looking for the htaccess file is this:
i placed  some code in index.php (right now just printing some string to a file but
eventually will do banner cycling) and i've noticed the string gets printed a few times when i load index.php. could that have some connection to the htaccess file?

thanx  in advance for any input.

Comment: It shouldn't have any connection. Can you please add what code have you changed (only relevant part)? If you roll back to original index.php, does the problem reveal itself?

Comment: thanx,
this is the relevant code in index.php:

file_put_contents($text_file, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ,FILE_APPEND );

and the output is:
/itportal.co.il/index.php
/itportal.co.il/index.php/uploads/76126568849640.png 
/itportal.co.il/index.php/uploads/13126494098846.jpg
/itportal.co.il/index.php/uploads/34126569172238.png
 /itportal.co.il/index.php/uploads/12125938246345.jpg
/itportal.co.il/index.php/uploads/35126534663389.jpg
etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simply checks whether a file exists (as a file -f, or directory -d).  If it does not, it takes the address and passes it to index.php.

For instance if you ask for:

`www.mysite.com/badfile.html`

You will get:

`www.mysite.com/index.php/badfile.html`

This should have no effect on how the code in index.php runs.  This only affects what happens when non-existent files and directories are requested.

Comment: thank you for answering. just to be clear - if badfile.htm is requested, will index.php be loaded again? - this would explain why the
code that prints to file runs a few times and not just on the initial loading of index.php.
if so, every time a non-existant file or dir is requested, the homepage gets reloaded, which is ,well, strange to me, at least..

this is the code in index.php
file_put_contents($text_file, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
,FILE_APPEND );
and the output is:
/itportal.co.il/index.php
/itportal.co.il/index.php/uploads/76126568849640.png 
...
etc..

Comment: If index.php requests badfile.html, then yes, index.php will be called again.  Basically, it will be called for every non-existent file that index.php requests.  This means you could end up with a loop of sorts, as the new call to index.php may request the bad file again.

Answer (score 0):

Request is for a file on the webserver, denies access to index.php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Request is for a physical directory on the webserver, denies access to index.php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Any other than the above, redirects to index.php

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```